# can i change the name of executable during compilation

Tags: llvm, clang

I'm compiling LLVM/Clang but want to give a different name to the executable. Is there a special option I need to be using, like `--binary-name`? The trick is that I want to rename every tool that comes with LLVM/Clang.

For example:

```
clang -> my-clang 
llvm-conig -> my-llvm-config
etc.
```

Is it even possible in Unix/Linux?

Comment: How many binaries are you talking about? If there are only a handful, I do not see why you could not use `mv` to rename them. You could also make a symbolic link the the binary with the name you prefer.

Comment: @ElixirofLove The idea is to have multiple versions of the tool installed. I need to compile different versions of clang/llvm and it would be nice if I could run clang-3.5, llvm-config-3.4 etc.

Comment: Clang doesn't support this while building: http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Why-is-there-no-configure-quot-program-suffix-quot-parameter-td3626561.html, so I suppose you'll have to do this manually.

Comment: Let me generalize the question. Is it possible to install multiple versions of the same tool on a *nix system? And if not then what are the best practices to do that? In addition should a *nix developers implement some sort of a management system in the future to solve this type of problem? If this comment is off topic, I'd appreciate if some moderator could create a separate discussion thread for it.

Comment: @flashburn it is possible. They do, they're called packages (with package managers). We don't have discussion threads on Stack Exchange, you can use chatrooms instead.

Comment: @muru Here is another question. Is there a generic package manager which I can use for various versions of the programs or I need a specific one for each program? For example, I think ruby is using something called rpm to managed multiple versions.

Comment: @flashburn there's no generic package manager. I think you meant RVM, but I don't use ruby and so not sure. Your (presumably Linux) distro likely uses a package manager (apt, yum, pacman, etc.). So, if you look for packages, look for those made for your distro's package manager.

Comment: @muru You are correct, I meant RVM. As far as I understand apt doesn't let one manage multiple versions of the same program. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @flashburn multiple versions of the same *package*, yes. That doesn't mean you can't have multiple packages with different source versions. Look at the gcc-x.y packages, for example.

Comment: Is my answer not what you are looking for? It definitely gets the job done... I do not think there is any way to change all names of binaries at compilation the way you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you can change the name of all binary files during compilation... but my suggestion would be to compile the program in the directory it came in, move than entire directory to `/usr/src`, then create a symbolic link to the main binary in `/usr/bin`.

`ln -s /usr/src/clang-3.5/bin/clang /usr/bin/clang-3.5`

This way you can have multiple versions of different programs and not worry about the older libraries, and other files, being overwritten when installing them.